# MySQL Data model for clinic appointment management system

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have few questions on the data model I am working on.

Its for an Appointment management system with few more details. For each appointment, we need to capture bunch of details.

**Approach 1:-**

All fields in 1 table.

**Fields :-**

```
1. appointment_id
2. doctor_id
3. client_id
4. appointment_type
5. start_time
6. end_time
7. notes
8. weight
9. weight_unit
10. temperature
11.temperature_unit
12.heart_rate
13.respiratory_rate
14.pulse_rate
15.hydration
16.systolic_bp
17.diastolic_bp
18.body_condition_code
19.pain_score
20.general_appearance
21.general_appearance_status
22.oral_health
23.oral_health_status   
24.eyes_health
25.eyes_health_status   
26.ears_health
27.ears_health_status   
28.lungs_health
29.lungs_health_status
....
....
...
 status
 created_by
 created_time
 updated_by
 updated_time
```

**Approach 2:-**

Appointment booking and other details in a separate table

**2 Separate Tables**

**Table 1:- Appointment**

```
1. appointment_id
2. doctor_id
3. client_id
4. appointment_type
5. start_time
6. end_time
7. notes
8. status
9. created_by
10. created_time
11.updated_by
12.updated_time
```

**Table 2:- Appointment_details**

```
1. appointment_id
2. doctor_id
3. client_id
4. weight
5. weight_unit
6. temperature
7.temperature_unit
8.heart_rate
9.respiratory_rate
10.pulse_rate
11.hydration
12.systolic_bp
13.diastolic_bp
14.body_condition_code
15.pain_score
16.general_appearance
17.general_appearance_status
18.oral_health
19.oral_health_status   
20.eyes_health
21.eyes_health_status   
22.ears_health
23.ears_health_status   
24.lungs_health
25.lungs_health_status
....
....
...
 status
 created_by
 created_time
 updated_by
 updated_time
```

**Approach 3:-**

Appointment booking, Appointment essentials and other details in a separate table

**3 Separate Tables**

**Table 1:- Appointment**

```
1. appointment_id
2. doctor_id
3. client_id
4. appointment_type
5. start_time
6. end_time
7. notes
8. status
9. created_by
10. created_time
11.updated_by
12.updated_time
```

**Table 2:- Appointment_essentials**

```
1. appointment_id
2. doctor_id
3. client_id
4. weight
5. weight_unit
6. temperature
7.temperature_unit
8.heart_rate
9.respiratory_rate
10.pulse_rate
11.hydration
12.systolic_bp
13.diastolic_bp
14.body_condition_code
15.pain_score
```

**Table 3:- Appointment_details**

```
    1. appointment_id
    2. doctor_id
    3. doctor_id
    4.general_appearance
    5.general_appearance_status
    6.oral_health
    7.oral_health_status   
    8.eyes_health
    9.eyes_health_status   
   10.ears_health
   11.ears_health_status   
   12.lungs_health
   13.lungs_health_status
    ....
    ....
    ...
     status
     created_by
     created_time
     updated_by
     updated_time
```

**Approach 4:-**

Appointment booking, Appointment essentials, Health_Parts_Prop and Health_Prop_Mapping

**4 Separate Tables**

**Table 1:- Appointment**

```
1. appointment_id
2. doctor_id
3. client_id
4. appointment_type
5. start_time
6. end_time
7. notes
8. status
9. created_by
10. created_time
11.updated_by
12.updated_time
```

**Table 2:- Appointment_essentials**

```
1. appointment_id
2. doctor_id
3. client_id
4. weight
5. weight_unit
6. temperature
7.temperature_unit
8.heart_rate
9.respiratory_rate
10.pulse_rate
11.hydration
12.systolic_bp
13.diastolic_bp
14.body_condition_code
15.pain_score
```

**Table 3:- health_part**

```
1. health_part_id
2. health_part_name
3. health_part_status_id
4. created_by
5. created_time
6. updated_by
7. updated_time
```

**Table 3:- appt_health_part_mapping**

```
 1. appt_id
   2. client_id
   4. health_part_id
   5. health_part_status_id
   6. value
   7. created_time
```

**Use cases:-**

1. Screen to store appointment with details like doctor, client, appointment_time, notes
2. Screen to show appointments in a weekly calendar for the logged in doctor
3. Screen for upcoming appointments for the day
4. Screen to store all the details after the appointment like all observations

So, during the appointment, there are few essentials which needs to be captured for all the appointments. And there are few details based on appointment like for some appointment, eyes and ears and for some appointment lungs and ears details.
Currently, the system is capturing few parts and that might change in the future.

So, Considering all the above facts, I have decided to go with the final approach.

Any thoughts on this?

Also, I may need to show the weight trends and height trends since birth.

Will the current design suffice?

Comment: As a matter of course, one should use more tables *if* one needs more tables to maintain consistency, avoid update errors, or provide flexibility.  As I see it from here, your current design isn't sufficient for reasons mainly around different types of appointments needing different measures, measurements being tightly coupled to appointments, etc. not just the difficulty that it might take querying things for height/weight trends.  So my question is: how much time/effort do you have to help craft a sufficiently detailed answer?

Comment: I have a plan to store weight and height alone in a separate tables just for the trends. Hope, that should suffice.

Comment: @bbaird, Please help with some directions as I want to take it in the right direction as we are still in the early stage. Also, this answer will be helpful for many others.

Comment: Let's continue in chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119785/discussion-on-question-database-design-by-user1578872